# How to create a PySpark dataframe from the output of a dataframe filter?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have to create 2 dataframes from a single dataframe based on a filter function.

`#df is an existing dataframe`

Condition for the first dataframe

`df.filter(df['Date'] == max_date ).display()`

Condition for the second dataframe

`df.filter(df['Date'] != max_date ).display()`

FYI, type of dataframe 'df' is:

`# <class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just assign the output to a new df.

```
new_df = df.filter(df['Date'] != max_date )
new_df2 = df.filter(df['Date'] == max_date )
```